# Executing JSON in Selenium

Tags: json, selenium, webdriver

I need to know the easiest way to execute JSON in a selenium test. An example would be i want to POST { "UserId":"234234" } and test against what is returned. Currently using Advanced REST client chrome app to manually test. I've done a lot of searching on this topic but haven't come across any good examples.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This doesn't sound like it's best solved by selenium.  With Selenium you would interact with the form to get that value to post, and handle the subsequent AJAX response / page refresh.  If you wish to POST data you should look at a library that performs those types of operations across the wire.

If you are looking for a HTTP library, then Apache has a [good one](http://hc.apache.org/httpclient-3.x/) (Java based).

Comment: well selenium does have a [json wire protocol](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/JsonWireProtocol) 
and i was shooting for some example of that

Comment: @AJ_Cemprola the protocol is for those who wish to create a new WebDriver instance, like the [ChromeDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/ChromeDriver), [SafariDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/SafariDriver), [IPhoneDriver](http://code.google.com/p/selenium/wiki/IPhoneDriver), etc...